# android accessibility dispatchGesture - is it possible to specify pressure for a stroke

Tags: android, accessibility, gesture, stroke

When generating a stroke via dispatchGesture() in an Android Accessibility service, is it possible to somehow specify the 'pressure' and 'size' for the stroke/gesture?  In looking at the Android code, it looks like the pressure and size are 'hard-coded' to be 1.0f.

```
GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, startTime, duration));
dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), new GestureResultCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) { .. }, 
}, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The current API doesn't support customizing gestures in that way. Sorry.